# how to merge the null column to get date range

Tags: sql, t-sql, select

the table is:

```
id  range_start range_end
---------------------------
1   NULL    2018-01-01
1   2018-02-11  NULL
1   NULL    NULL
1   NULL    2018-04-09
1   NULL    NULL
2   2018-05-01  NULL
2   NULL    2018-08-01
```

the code:

```
create table #test(id int,range_start date,range_end date)
insert #test values(1,null,'2018-01-01'),
                   (1,'2018-02-11',null),
                   (1,null,null),
                   (1,null,'2018-04-09'),
                   (1,null,null),
                   (2,'2018-05-01',null),
                   (2,null,'2018-08-01')
```

and I want the output can ignore the null value:

```
id  range_start range_end
---------------------------
1   NULL    2018-01-01
1   2018-02-11  2018-04-09
2   2018-05-01  2018-08-01
```

The first column can be reserved.
Thank you very much,

Comment: what do you mean by `The first column can be reserved` ?

Comment: @Squirrel I think it has to do with the edge case where there is no initial starting date of the first range.  In that case, the starting date should be reported as `NULL`.

Comment: This problem would be much easier if we didn't have to worry about the possible missing start date.  Is there any chance you could scrub your data before attempting this query?

Comment: It means that there is no starting date, so I insert the null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, min(range_start) range_start, max(range_end) range_end
from (
  select *, row_number()over(partition by id order by coalesce(range_start, range_end))
               + case when range_end is null then 1 else 0 end rn
  from #test
  where range_start is not null or range_end is not null
)a
group by id, rn
order by 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `APPLY` :

```
select t.id, isnull(t.range_start, t1.range_start) as range_start, t.range_end
from #test t outer apply
     ( select top (1) t1.*
       from #test t1 
       where t1.id = t.id and t1.range_start is not null and t.range_end > t1.range_start
       order by t1.range_start desc
     ) t1
WHERE t.range_end is not null;
```